# Java Jersey HTTPS GET request with Authentication header

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-client

I'm trying to integrate a payment service 'Mollie' (http://www.mollie.nl) which works over HTTPS requests into a Java environment.

As for this posts i'll be using following request to explain:
Within PHP (since I have a PHP background) I can work with cURL:

```
$ curl -X GET https://api.mollie.nl/v1/methods \
-H "Authorization: Bearer API-KEY"
```

Which has a response:

[image]

Testing the REQUEST from DHC (or Postman) return correct response.

[image]

So within Java i'm using the Jersey library to try to access the Request:

```
    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource =   client.resource("https://api.mollie.nl/v1/methods");
    webResource.header("Authorization", "Bearer API-KEY");
    ClientResponse response = webResource    
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
            .type("application/json")
            .accept("application/json")
            .get(ClientResponse.class);

    int statusCode = response.getStatus();
    if (statusCode == 401) {
        throw new AuthenticationException("Invalid Username or Password");
    }

    String responseCall = response.getEntity(String.class);
```

When executing the Java code the request throws a ClientHandlerException:

```
HTTP Status 500 - com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

I'm running the Java test from a Apache localhost server.
But I can't figure out why the Java request gives a timeout since the authentication header seems to be set correct (at least to me).

What I did notice is when visiting the path of the request https://api.mollie.nl/v1/methods it shows a pop-up for authentication.

It would be nice to get some usefull tips or information about this issue.
Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Running your java code gave me `GET https://api.mollie.nl/v1/methods returned a response status of 401 Unauthorized`, so it doesn't look like that's the issue.

Comment: @daan.desmedt looks like there is a problem with the service 500 is an internal server error...

Comment: [ConnectException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/net/ConnectException.html) relates to the underlying socket connection, so I don't think it has anything to do with the authorization header, which is part of a higher level protocol. The full stack trace should show that clearly, would you mind posting it?

Comment: Sure, http://pastebin.com/dSGv50sD. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved above issue. Apparently the work PROXY server was blocking outgoing HTTPS requests. Testing from a non-proxy environment fixed the issue. Thanks for all advice!

Comment: Happens all the time :/

Answer (score 6):

Given all is is working correctly (I'm not sure why it would cause a timeout), one thing I see wrong is your usage of

```
webResource.header("Authorization", "Bearer API-KEY");
```

[`header`](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.18/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.html#header%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) returns an [`WebResource.Builder`](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.18/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.Builder.html), and **does not** add the header to the current `WebResource`. So the request you are sending doesn't have the header. You can check it by adding a `LoggingFilter`

```
client.addFilter(new com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.LoggingFilter(System.out));
```

You can fix this by doing

```
ClientResponse response = webResource
        .header("Authorization", "Bearer API-KEY");    
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
```

Just moving the header to the method chaining.